# "ignorance" can also mean a "willful disregard of something"?

Tags: vocabulary

I try to use the 2nd or 3rd definition of words (to slow down speed readers). However, I am not sure if "ignorance" has a 2nd definition.

(common meaning)  is "a lack of knowledge". With this meaning, no syllable is stressed.

- *My ignorance of hardware means I cannot build my own pc.*

(2nd meaning?) If pronounced differently, I think that "ignorance" can also mean "a willful and careless disregard of something". The "nor" syllable in "ig-NOR-ance" must be stressed.

- *The French were aware of the strategic weakness of the Maginot Line, and their ignorance of it enabled the German blitz through the Low Countries*.
- *My ignorance of my girlfriend's hourly text messages quickly caused our break-up.*

In a dictionary, "ignorance" is only defined as "lack of knowledge". But, I am not talking about that "ignorance". I am talking about the "ignorance" that is derived from "to ignore" and thus pronounced just like "to ignore", and thus has the meaning of "to ignore". There is precedence for this:

"to accept" --- derive ---> "acceptance"
"to ignore" --- derive ---> "ignorance"
....

Anyone agree with me?

Comment: Ignorance can be either intensional or accidental. Accidental ignorance is the normal state of humankind; intensional ignorance, on the other hand, is perhaps the only real sin.

Comment: @John: I was "accidentally ignorant" of the difference between *intensional ignorance* and *intentional ignorance* when I first read your comment. After reading [Wikipedia's definition of **intensional**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensional_definition), I'm still not really any the wiser. I can understand that I might now be *wilfully/intentionally ignorant* because I've deliberately not made the effort to fully grok the linguistics term, but what would it mean if I was *intensionally ignorant?* (Apart from the fact that apparently I won't be going to heaven when I die :).

Comment: Well, I simply misspelled it. So don't go waxing too philosophic.

Comment: I agree with you (partly). I've heard a few times (in my head it's said in a female Scottish accent, lord knows what I must have done wrong at the time) _You did that out of ignorance_ most definitely meaning _You did that wilfully and maliciously_ (rather than because you didn't know better). No difference in pronunciation though I think.

Comment: I don't have any sources to back this up, but I've heard it used the second way colloquially in the UK, e.g. "I don't like it when he puts football on while I'm in the room. It's ignorant" meaning the football fan was rudely ignoring the speaker. It's not something I'd use in conversation personally though.

Comment: I started thinking if I have ever been intentionally ignorant in my life...but if it was intentional, I should be able to remember...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most dictionaries show usages which are reasonably common, to explain what might be happened across. Thus there is a lower limit, below which a particular dictionary might not mention a usage even though it has been used.

The OED's lower limit is very low; it's a historical dictionary. *Ignorance* appears in three main senses:

> **1. 
>    a.** The fact or condition of being ignorant; want of knowledge (general or special).
>   **b.** Constr. *of* (†*in*, or subord. clause).
>   **c.** With *an* and *pl.*: An instance or example of ignorance. rare.
>   †**2.** With *an* and *pl.* An act due to want of knowledge; an offence or sin caused by ignorance.
>   **3.** (In full ***the time* or *days of ignorance***; tr. Arabic *jāhilīyah* state of ignorance, < *jāhil* ignorant.) The period of Arabian history previous to the teaching of Muhammad.

This doesn't mention your usage at all, even as an obsolete sense (with a dagger mark) which could possibly be revived.

So no, *ignorance* doesn't mean *ignoring. Ignorance* only means lack of knowledge, and has never meant the deliberate act of ignoring. So you would need to use that word.

> My ignoring of my girlfriend's hourly text messages quickly caused our break-up.

OED shows the etymology:

> < French *ignorance* (12th cent. in Littré) = Italian *ignoranzia,* Spanish *ignorancia,* < Latin *ignōrāntia, < ignōrānt-em* **ignorant** *adj.* and *n.*

...and *ignorant* there simply means "one who has no knowledge" of something.

It is in fact ***ignore*** which has changed its meaning over time. OED has first the obsolete sense related to *ignorance*:

> †**1.** *trans.* Not to know, to be ignorant of. *Obs.* or *rare.*

Over time, *ignore* has become rather more deliberate. One has no knowledge of something because one has **chosen** to have no knowledge of it.

*Ignorance* has not followed this path.

Comment: And in French, _ignorer_ still means _not know_, which can lead to misunderstanding when a French speaker mistakenly says _ignore_ in English, intending that meaning.

Comment: Nice comments on how dictionaries work, but 'The OED's lower limit is very low; it's a historical dictionary' strongly suggests that there is a necessary connection between the two statements. Historical dictionaries, like all others, may be more or less comprehensive (though they will all undoubtedly include senses that modern-usage dictionaries deliberately omit).

Answer (score 2):

"Ignorance" doesn't generally imply willful lack of knowledge. If you stress the NOR, it would be clear what you meant in speech, but for writing, I would use "By ignoring my girlfriend's hourly text messages, I quickly caused our break-up." It not only has clearer meaning, but also a more active voice. You might also consider "neglect" if you want to imply that reading the texts was an unfulfilled responsibility.

Comment: Even though it is wrong, I still might use "ignorance" as "willful disregard" just to make how I communicate more interesting. But, you are absolutely correct. I can't do it in writing. I have to stress the "nor" syllable, or else it sounds very unnatural and is confusing. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a second definition either. However, as I expect you would know, ignore is a verb that would enable you to say "My *ignoring* of my girlfriend's hourly text messages . . ." That would convey that you made a decision to not expose yourself to the information.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to exist confusion between the **noun** *ignorance* and the **verb** *ignore* as well as how to use these words in a sentence.

The word *ignorant* is an *adjective* describing a person in a state of unintentional or deliberate unawareness.

**ig·no·rance** *ˈiɡnərəns/* noun: lack of knowledge or information. "he acted in ignorance of basic procedures"

*synonyms*: incomprehension of, unawareness of, unconsciousness of, unfamiliarity with, inexperience with, lack of knowledge about, lack of information about;

*antonyms*: understanding, familiarity, knowledge, education

versus

**ig·nore** *iɡˈnôr/* verb: refuse to take notice of or acknowledge; disregard intentionally. "he ignored her outraged question"

*synonyms*: disregard, take no notice of, pay no attention to, pay no heed to;

*more*: fail to consider (something significant); "direct satellite broadcasting ignores national boundaries"

*legal*: (of a grand jury) reject (an indictment) as groundless.

Comment: I have quite a strong (but possibly also quite incorrect) recollection of, many years ago, hearing a recording (from many years prior to that) of an American-accented boxer on a BBC Radio programme.  He was being asked about likes and dislikes or similar and said something like "I can't stand it when people don't pay attention to me. I really can't stand ignorance."    How I laughed!  Until - my recollection goes - I looked up "ignorance" in some dictionary I had to hand (Internet was probably dial-up at the time) and found a definition along the lines of "to ignore something".  Dammit!

Answer (score 0):

Given these famous quotes:

"The ignorant can be educated, but you can't fix stupid."
- (approximated) possibly Mark Twain?

“We are all born ignorant, but one must work hard to remain stupid.” 
― Benjamin Franklin

“Being ignorant is not so much a shame, as being unwilling to learn.” 
― Benjamin Franklin

"If we're looking for the source of our troubles, we shouldn't test people for drugs, we should test them for stupidity, ignorance, greed and love of power.” 
― P.J. O'Rourke

It's clear that we generally agree that stupid means incapable of learning, but ignorant means different things to different people. (Or even the same person, in the case of Ben Franklin. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the word u were looking for is ignoration. Merriam Webster’s defines it as a noun, with its second sense being:

> [ignore + -ation] : an act or action of ignoring.
> *Changed from complete ignoration of my presence to an almost pathetic agreement with every word I said
> —H. J. Laski*

So this sense comes from the deliberate ‘to ignore’ as in, ‘I’m ignoring you now.’

But ‘ignoration’ can also mean the other kind of ignore, the non-deliberate kind, according to Merriam Webster’s:

> complete or utter **ignorance**.
> *The ignoration of the true relation of each organism to its environment
> —A. N. Whitehead*

Just search up ‘ignoration’ on Merriam Webster’s online dictionary and it should turn up.